# Wireshark MATE: Calculate response time

Tags: wireshark, mate

I'm just trying to use MATE to calculate response time between each SMPP submit_sm and submit_sm_resp, this is the mate script I'm using:

```
Pdu smpp_pdu Proto smpp Transport mate { 
   Extract cmd From smpp.command_id; 
   Extract seq From smpp.sequence_number;
};
Gop smpp_session On smpp_pdu Match (seq) { 
   Start (cmd=4); 
   Stop (cmd=2147483652);
};
Done;
```

So basically, it exacts command id and sequence numbers, then in Gop uses command id for start/stop

4 = 0x00000004 = SUBMIT_SM

2147483652 = 0x80000004 = SUBMIT_SM_RESP

This should do the trick. But, now what?
I added a column with Delta Time Displayed, and this should show the response time for each submit_sm_resp, but this is not using MATE, just calculate the time between each previous packet:

[image: image description]

How can I use MATE script?

If I use the following filter in a specific column:
mate.smpp_pdu.RelativeTime

I only got the seconds, for each packet, from starting trace:

[image: image description]

As far I understood, MATE should setup time between START and STOP, but which is the filter I should use?
This doesn't shown anything:
mate.smpp_session.Time

Please advise,
Thank you,
Lucas

Answer (score 0):

Find solution! I posted here just in case someone need it:

Because cmd is a string, the correct Gop will be:

```
Start (cmd="0x00000004"); 
Stop (cmd="0x80000004");
```

This will did the trick.